# How to emit error to be possible catch it on error handler on client-side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I need to emit error in my connection handler and catch it on client-side something like this:

// server-side

```
var http = require('http');
var sio = require('socket.io');
var app = require('express')();

var server = require('http').createServer(app).listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server listening on 3000 port');
});

var io = sio.listen(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // Do something and emit error...
    socket.emit('error', new Error('Some error happened'));
});
```

// client-side

```
var socket = io.connect(window.location.origin);
socket.on('error', function () {
   console.log('Never happens...');
});
```

But the problem is `socket.emit('error', new Error('Some error happend'));` on server-side always throws error and crashes nodejs server due [this issue](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2285)

Could you help how to emit error and handle on client side properly?

Comment: "error" seems to be reserved, why can't you just just use another name, like "errorEvent"?

Comment: @cviejo I can but I need to handle that case in error case. `errorEvent` will not trigger error event handler

Comment: Ah, i see now. The question below was edited to answer that too

Answer (score 14, accepted):

server

```
socket.emit('my error', 'Some error happened');
```

client

```
socket.on('my error', function (text) {
   console.log(text);
});
```

`error` is a reserved name, unfortunately.

If you need to catch it on client side, use some other event name to notify client

```
// server
socket.on("error", function() {
    socket.emit("my error", "Something bad happened!");
});

// client
socket.on('my error', function (text) {
   console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: The following events should not be emitted: error, connect, disconnect, disconnecting, newListener, removeListener, ping, pong.
They're listed at the bottom of this documentation page https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

Comment: @PeterDvukhrechensky Page Not Found ...

Comment: @GennadiyRyabkin they have restructured their doc section. The URL now depends on the version you use. The page I pointed to in my previous comment was for version 2 and it's now here [socket.io/docs/v2/emit-cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/v2/emit-cheatsheet/)
There are two more cheatsheets for version 3 and version 4. [socket.io/docs/v3/emit-cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/v3/emit-cheatsheet/)
[socket.io/docs/v4/emit-cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/v4/emit-cheatsheet/)