# Can not emit event with socketid

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, integration-testing

I am trying to write an integration test for socket io. I am using try-catch for server event when the error is catched I emit an event for the client to handle the error

```
io.of('/rooms').on('connection', socket => {
        const socketId = socket.id;
        console.log('server socketid', socketId);
        const userRepository = getCustomRepository(UserRepository);
        const conversationToUserRepository = getCustomRepository(ConversationToUserRepository);

        socket.on('initGroupChat', async (users_id, fn) => {
            try {
                const [user, listConversationToUser] = await Promise.all([
                    userRepository.findOne({
                        where: {
                            users_id,
                        },
                    }),
                    conversationToUserRepository.find({
                        where: {
                            users_id,
                        },
                    }),
                ]);
            if (!user) {
                throw new NotFoundError('User not found with id: ' + users_id);
            }

            console.log(2);

            user.socket_id = socket.id;
            await userRepository.save(user);

            for (const item of listConversationToUser) {
                socket.join(item.conversation_id.toString());
            }
            fn('init group chat success');
        } catch (error) {
            io.to(socketId).emit('error', errorHandlerForSocket(error));
            console.log(10);
        }
    });
});
```

but on the socket client, nothing happens. here is the code socket client:

```
it.only('Init Group Chat with error', done => {
        socket = io.connect(`http://localhost:${env.app.port}/rooms`, {
            transports: ['websocket']
        });



   const id = 11111;
    socket.emit('initGroupChat', id, (response: any) => {
        console.log('response', response);
    });

    socket.on('error', (error: any) => {
        console.log('error3', error);
        done();
    });

});
```

on the error event, the console.log did not show on the terminate. it didn't catch the event I emit on the server.

can anyone help me fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time the client Refresh socketId changes.

Server :

```
io.emit("send_to_client", {
   userId: 112233,
   data: "Hello user 112233"
});
```

Client :

```
 var userLogin = 112233;
 socket.on("send_to_client", function(res) {
  if(res.userId === userLogin)
    //somethingElse
});
```

Comment: this isn't working, `io.emit('error', errorHandlerForSocket(error));`, the event error doesn't receive the error

Comment: try : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872052/how-to-emit-error-to-be-possible-catch-it-on-error-handler-on-client-side)